# Number of Strings with two specific letters

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

How many ways can you construct a string four letters (from 26 alphabet characters) that have both the letters j and k in them?

Comment: Do you mean exactly one $j$ and exactly one $k$?

Comment: No, at least one of each :o)

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to count the complement.

There are $25^4$ strings that don't have $j$, and $25^4$ that don't have $k$. If we add these, we will count twice the strings that have neither $j$ nor $k$. There are $24^4$ of these. So the required number is
$$26^4 -\left(25^4+25^4-24^4\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd solve is by looking at the total number of ways of constructing a 4-bit string out of 26 letters, which is $26^4$ and the number of ways you can construct a 4-bit string with neither $i$ nor $j$, which is $24^4$, so your result should be $26^4-24^4$